# Unable to insert into table with Identity Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this procedure:

```
create proc insertfactors_pf
(
    @FactorID int,
    @CustomersID int,
    @Number int,
    @TotalPrice decimal(18, 0),
    @PaidPrice decimal(18, 0),
    @Date Date,
    @ProductID int,
    @QTY int

)
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SET IDENTITY_INSERT facetors on


INSERT INTO Factor VALUES (@FactorID, @CustomersID, @Number, @TotalPrice, @PaidPrice,@Date)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT factors off

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Product_Factor on
INSERT INTO Produc_Factor values(@FactorID,@ProductID,@QTY)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Product_Factor off


IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END

COMMIT
```

But when I run it I get this error:

> Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Procedure insertfactors_pf, Line 20 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   An explicit value for the identity column in table 'Factor' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is Sql Server syntax, not MySql. Please be more aware of your tag choices.

Comment: Given the number of typo's in this script (e.g. `SET IDENTITY_INSERT **facetors** on`, `INSERT INTO **Produc_Factor**`) I find it difficult to believe this script is what was actually run. In the future, please cut-and-paste your actual script, rather than re-typing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear: `FactorId` is an identity column. *You shouldn't set the value for FactorID yourself.* Sql Server will set it for you. But if you really want to set it for some insane reason, you need to include a column list in the query like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT facetors on
    INSERT INTO Factor 
        (FactorID, CustomerID, Number, TotalPrice, PaidPrice, Date)
    VALUES 
        (@FactorID, @CustomersID, @Number, @TotalPrice, @PaidPrice,@Date)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT factors off
```

Even better, you should do something more like this, where you don't have to mess with identity insert issues:

```
create proc insertfactors_pf
(
    @CustomersID int,
    @Number int,
    @TotalPrice decimal(18, 0),
    @PaidPrice decimal(18, 0),
    @Date Date,
    @ProductID int,
    @QTY int
)
AS

--Move this to inside the procedure definition. Don't ask for it as an argument
DECLARE @FactorID int

BEGIN TRANSACTION

--Don't mention FactorID anywhere here. Sql Server will take care of it
INSERT INTO Factor
    (CustomersID, Number, TotalPrice, PaidPrice, Date)
VALUES 
    (@CustomersID, @Number, @TotalPrice, @PaidPrice,@Date);

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN 
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END

--use scope_idenity() to get the FactorID value Sql Server just created
SELECT @FactorID = scope_identity();

INSERT INTO Produc_Factor 
    (FactorID, ProductID, Qty)
VALUES 
    (@FactorID,@ProductID,@QTY)

IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK
    RETURN
END

COMMIT
```

Comment: This is only one of the two inserts. Fix both of them. Better yet, **don't set the FactorID column yourself at all!**